# How to correctly argue that this function preserves the norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, solution-verification

I have a function $\phi:L^2(-\pi,\pi)\to l^2$, defined by $$(\phi(x))_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x(t)e^{-ikt}dt, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ I have to argue that this function **preserves the norm**. I have to show that $$\Vert\phi(x)\Vert_{l^2}=\Vert x\Vert_{L^2}$$
My approach was this:

Let $$(\phi(x))_k=\langle x(t),e^{ikt}\rangle$$ where $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{ikt}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a orthonormal system. By the Riesz–Fischer theorem I can state that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\vert\langle x(t),e^{ikx}\rangle\vert^2=\Vert x(t)\Vert^2$$
so
$$\Vert\phi(x)\Vert_{l^2}=\Vert x\Vert_{L^2}$$

This is my best attempt on this problem, I don't know if its correct though. I'm currently studying functional analysis and this is a problem in a book about this topic. Sorry if the way how this "proof" is done is sloppy!

Would really appreciate some comments and would be glad if someone could point out some mistakes I made. Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof is fine. That is the only way anyone would answer this question!

Comment: Some details: I wouldn't say "Let $(\phi(x))_k=...$ since $\phi$ is defined this way and thus the equation holds by the definition of the scalar product in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. And then since $\psi_k(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{ikt}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ form an orthonormal system by Riesz-Fischer $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|\langle x, \psi_k\rangle |^2=||x||_{L^2}$, note the lower bound, the notation $\langle x(t),e^{ikt}\rangle$ is quite sloppy, and you missed the factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, lateron you write $e ^{ikx}$. Anyway if you correct these little inaccuracies Your proof is fine

Comment: I made mistakes by myself : of course it must be an orthonormal $\textbf{basis}$ and it is $||x||_{L^2}^2$....